# Questions on UFT/QTP 11.53

Tags: wpf, automation, qtp, gui-testing, hp-uft

1. We use citrix servers where our applications are located , It is quite impossible for us to say on which citrix sessions our AUT would open. So, Is it necessary that even the sessions of UFT/Testcomplete and the AUT should be the same?
2. Our applications are made of .NET 4.5. Does UFT 11.53 and TestComplete support .NET 4.5?
3. Almost all controls in our applications are built using custom WPF controls. How compatible is UFT with these. No 3rd party resources have been used in combination with WPF except microsoft's packages.

Your insights would be of great help! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About UFT:

- Yes, UFT can only record the AUT from same session. So I suggest you to install UFT on the citrix server, and launch together with the AUT．
- UFT 11.53 supports .Net 4.5.
- You can test most custom WPF controls inherited directly or
  indirectly from the System.Windows.Controls.Control class regardless
  of which language was used to create the application (for example,
  Visual Basic, .NET, C#, and so on), as well as third-party WPF
  controls that are inherited from the System.Windows.Controls.Control
  class and implement automation interfaces.
  If the WPF controls are not supported out-of-box by WPF Add-in, you can use WPF Add-in Extensibility to teach UFT how to treat your custom controls. (This need programming skills)

Hope I've clarified your questions.